# Wordpress 301 Redirect not working

Tags: redirect, 404-error, duplicates

**Problem:**
There is a dulicate site that is still referenced in some sites maybe, is there way to check the ingoing links to that site?

I have a new site, that shall be online, and it is in some places, but I want to be sure it is redirected to always.

**What I tried:**
I use the settings -> 301 redirect, I update as I prefer but either 404 comes afterwards or the redirect does link to the old site (duplicate). I also used the repair tool, cleared the Wordpress and all Browser caches, but same issue.

The log:
https://pastebin.com/g1uzEKeT

Thx in advance!